# Where is the reference to static library in the Visual C++ project in VS 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker

I should have the reference to the same static library in 2 my projects in the same solution.  While linking one project has this reference, another one does not have. So I am getting link errors in the 2nd project. However, I can see the difference only in the  .vcxproj file:

One has the line:

```
<AdditionalOptions>/ERRORREPORT:PROMPT ..\debug\membraneStaticLibr.lib DelayImp.lib %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
```

Another one does not have this line.  Please see the surrounded code below.

Where is this difference to the static library reflected in the project properties from Visual C++ GUI?

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
<ClCompile>
  <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
  <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
  <MinimalRebuild>false</MinimalRebuild>
  <BasicRuntimeChecks>Default</BasicRuntimeChecks>
  <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebug</RuntimeLibrary>
  <RuntimeTypeInfo>true</RuntimeTypeInfo>
  <PrecompiledHeader />
  <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
  <DebugInformationFormat>EditAndContinue</DebugInformationFormat>
</ClCompile>
<Link>
  <AdditionalOptions>/ERRORREPORT:PROMPT ..\debug\membraneStaticLibr.lib DelayImp.lib %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
  <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
  <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
  <TargetMachine>MachineX86</TargetMachine>
  <LinkErrorReporting />
</Link>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *AdditionalOptions* field can be found in *Project Properties*->*Configuration Properties*->*Linker*->*Command Line*.
However this is not ok to specify dependencies in there. Use either *Additional Dependencies* field in *Linker*, or even better, project references in *Common Properties*.

Comment: The Linker Command line was exactly the same for both project. So, the origin of " <AdditionalOptions>/ERRORREPORT:PROMPT ..\debug\membraneStaticLibr.lib" is still a puzzle.  Setting project references in Common Properties helped